# Supplying arguments to a bash script that uses "read" rather than $#

Tags: bash, ubuntu-8.04

A bash script was provided to me by a sysadmin which requires three values to be input by me.  The values are read using "read" rather than read directly from the command-line.

```
echo "Enter value:"
read myValue
echo "Enter value 2:"
read myOtherValue
```

The three values I'd be entering are predictable, and I need to run this script frequently, so I would like to automate it; however, simply executing the script with the params in the command-line does not work.

```
./script.sh myValue myOtherValue
```

I can supply the first value if I echo it and then pipe it to the script, but that only works for the first param.  I don't know how to pass the rest of them in this fashion.

```
echo "myValue" | ./script.sh
```

I do not have access to modify the script to just read the arguments.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are truely unable to copy this script to your home folder and make modifications to suit your needs, you should look into expect.  Expect can read/write stdin/stdout to a program in an automated fashion.

This guide looks decent:
http://www.ftlinuxcourse.com/FTLinuxCourse_Complete-2004/FTLinuxCourse/en/sysadm/chap5_3.html

Comment: Leave it to me to try to over-engineer a solution when the path of least resistance is right in front of me.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you referring to making a copy, or using expect?  :)

Answer (score 5):

If the number of inputs is static you could use a here document:

```
cat <<FIN | ./script.sh
value1
value2
FIN
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo -e "MyValue\nMyOtherValue" | ./script.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to **Gerald Combs**' answer, you can use process substitution and redirection:

```
./script.sh < <(echo -e "myValue\nmyOtherValue")
```

or

```
./script.sh < <(echo "myValue
myOtherValue")
```

or

```
./script.sh < <(cat <<EOF
myValue
myOtherValue
EOF
)
```

or even:

```
./script.sh < <(echo "myValue"; echo "myOtherValue")
```

Where, instead of two "echoes", you might have two different commands that produce the output you need for input to the script.

Comment: Shouldn't the last one read ./script.sh < <(echo "myValue"; echo "myOtherValue") ?